# Are the Van Allen belts important to life?

Tags: radiation, space

Is it significant for life on Earth?

Mars doesn't have this. Why do experts think there may be life on it?

What kind of life form could live on Mars?

This article I just read got me wondering.

[A giant crater on Mars may have been able to support microbial life for millions of years in the ancient past because it was once a huge lake of water, new results from NASA's Curiosity rover suggest.](http://www.space.com/27950-mars-crater-lake-curiosity-rover.html)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the possible effects of stimuli on the development/growth of life and not about physics.

Comment: lack of reserch effort

Comment: Where does this question belong? Chemistry? Biology?